# nodejs socket .io check if cookies expired

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, cookies

I'm trying to check the cookies expiration of my Node + express + socket.io chat application.

This is how I set the session cookies.

```
io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
cookie(data, {}, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        var sessionID = data.signedCookies[ _key ];
        store.get(sessionID, function (err, session) {
            if (err || !session) {
                accept(null, false);
            } else {
                data.session = session;
                console.log( 'Auth: ', data.session);
                if (session.hasOwnProperty('username') ) {
                    accept(null, true);
                } else {
                    console.log( 'Auth: Failed!');
                    return accept('No session', false);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        return accept(null, false);
    }
  });
});
```

And this is how I get the session cookies

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function(socket){ 
var _sess = socket.handshake.session;});
```

How can I check if the current session cookies is going to expire? I wanted to show the user that his/her session is going to expired or already expired.

Comment: I suggest to handle this check at client end itself (apart from authentication at server). Consider going through this [link](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/12au/lectures/slides/lecture21-client-storage.shtml#slide1)

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni thanks for your reply. I already tried that approach, but what I found out is that the cookies from the node server is HTTP enabled. How can I manage to do check it with HTTP enabled cookie?